Pycharm does not open files
Onedrive somehow moved some files from my project folder on my PC to the trash.
After I noticed this, I restored them, but in pycharm all these files were colored green (olive) in the projects panel (located on the left side).
These colored files are not opened by pycharm, but the files themselves were not corrupted, they are opened by the OS.
Attempt:
I tried to reboot from disk and restore the IDE in the file, the file temporarily recovers (repaints white and opens) but after a while it repaints green again and stops opening.
I have also tried changing the file path, but that was not successful
I use: Windows 10 licensed and Pycharm 2022.3

In general it is a bad idea placing a project of an IDE in a OneDrive folder.

Or any cloud-managed folder.

Yeah, I realized that already, I'm using it now
